# "His emotions are fighting" What is the best word that can be put instead of fighting?

Tags: single-word-requests, writing

I am writing a fan-fiction right now and I am stuck. What I want to say is that there is a girl who cannot fall asleep because there a lot of stuff in her head and she cannot get them off her mind. Earlier, her mom took away her computer and she will go for a walk with friends sometime today. So, she's excited for the walk and also angry because her computer was taken away.

Comment: This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. You might want to consider writers.se.

Comment: *Muddled emotions* ?

Comment: The emotions are *warring*.

Comment: A common epithet is [*conflicting* or *conflicted* emotions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotional_conflict). But there isn't really a lot to go on in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“*His emotions are in conflict*”

*In conflict* is a typical way to describe this situation, as you can see in [Google Books results for “emotions in conflict”](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22emotions%20in%20conflict%22)

Answer (score 2):

NB: As the text is about a girl, the correct adjective is HER:
"Her conflicting emotions pulled her this way and that, (leaving her) sleeplesss.."

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.